# Relative path not working at all in WAMP local environment

Tags: images, html, paths

As you can see from below, the logo is in the same folder as header.php. I do the relative image reference in header.php by

img src="logo.png"

Its not working. Please help

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the png lies directly in your theme folder try this:

```
img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/logo.png"
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However, I could you give me an answer to another option I tried and not worked. I tried get_template_directory_uri. '/images/logo.png' where the logo was inside images. But did not work. When I inspected the elements, the hyperlink was correct and I verified it by pasting that link in another tab. The image showed up. But not in the main file

Comment: it should work. can you post a link to your site or show the produced html?